# Chromecast no longer pulls stream from the internet (YouTube)?

Tags: chromecast

I believe at one point when I was inside of Google Chrome and I said to cast YouTube, Chromecast would pull the stream from the internet itself.

This ability is [verified from this post here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2604433). You can also see if verified in this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29347443/124486). Now I'm wondering why it is that cast now just casts the tab "Chrome Mirroring", rather than sending the signal for Chromecast to pull just the stream from YouTube directly. It's slower, requires more throughput, and degrades the quality of the stream.

How do I get back the functionality of getting Chromecast to pull the video stream from YouTube when I hit the cast button, and not merely screencast?

I believe Chrome on Linux is no longer telling Chromecast the right thing. It's stuck on Mirroring the tab. Does anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worst UI award goes to Google. A lot of people are having this problem. [Google responded](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chromecast/jodaOLU_axc/fAqohkGxAgAJ),

> Grace Y. said: Hi there,
>
> Thanks for the screenshot.  So, I tested out Youtube myself and have
>   figured out why your'e getting mirroring as opposed to the Youtube app
>   itself.  First, there was a misunderstanding on my part, and tab
>   casting will start up the Youtube app. As you can see in the picture
>   below, when you first select cast in your Chrome Browser, you'll see a
>   list of your Chromecast devices. Instead of selecting your casting
>   device, select the "Cast to" dropdown menu.
>
> [image: Cast to]
>
> Afterwards, you'll the next screen asking you to select your source:
>
> [image: Select something else]
>
> Instead of choosing "Cast tab", you should be selecting the
>   youtube.com option.  Selecting this option should start up the Youtube
>   app on your TV.
>
> Hope this resolves your issue, and let me know how it goes.
>
> Best,  Grace

That's right, to send the URL to Chromecast, you have to click on "Cast to". If that's not [Mystery Meat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mystery_meat_navigation), not sure what is.